# Install jemalloc on Centos 8

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, centos8, rocksdb, jemalloc

I was checking this [Confluent article](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html#rocksdb) and decided to change RocksDB’s default memory allocator.

Yum can't find the formula jemalloc, though. Is there an easy way to install it in CentOS 8 without having to build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
yum install epel-release

yum install jemalloc
```